# Printing multiple selected documents

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing

We have a page on our site where we store incoming documents being uploaded (jpg, txt, png and pdf)

[image]

We've tried converting all selected documents into their base 64 representation and then merging them all into one document. This worked until we added in a pdf with multiple pages. Additionally, as you might imagine, converting all these into base64 and then merging them kills us on performance.

All we need, is the ability to select multiple files and print them sequentially. Like a queue or printer job if you will. I've looked far and wide for a solution and am coming up dry.

The closest libraries I've come to being close to what I need are [print.js](http://printjs.crabbly.com/) and [node-printer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-printer).

Any help here would be greatly appreciated as we're hitting a wall in figuring out how we can check off multiple files and have them printed sequentially.

Comment: You can use `focus` event to call next function in queue when previous `print()` job completes. Or, allow user to `click` a button to perform next `print()` job in queue.

Comment: what queue are you referring to? An array of selected files? or an actual queue method?

Comment: Both. An array of URL's which are requested and printed by a function in sequence.

Comment: @MrBoutte' did you find any solution for your question? We are trying to find a solution for the same problem.

Comment: Any update on the subject ? We have the same requirement. Prompting potentially 3000 times is not user friendly :(

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried merging all the files into one PDF document (js PDF library) anything possible these days

Comment: He says he tried merging the files into one but didn't work in all cases. Also, there are multiple types of files and it should be done programmatically.